# perform protocol Class method at a dynamically created class

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here's my situation:

I have a protocol with a class method that parses an NSDictionary and returns an object that performs my protocol:

```
@protocol RCParsableObject <NSObject>
/** 
  Parses an object from an NSDictionary representation
  Return: A object created from the NSDictionary representation
 */
+(id<RCParsableObject>)parseObjectFromDictonary:(NSDictionary*)object;
@end
```

At a part of my code I have the name of a class that performs that protocol in an NSString:

```
//dict is the dictionary I want to parse
Class class= NSClassFromString(type);
if ([class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RCParsableObject)]) {
   //NSObject* object = [class parseObjectFromDictionary:dict];//Obviously that don't works but shows what I want     
}
```

Inside the if I want to perform the Class method of the protocol that I know it can be performed because of the if.  How I can do that? It's a equivalent to:

```
NSObject * object = [class performSelector:_selector];
```

For a Class object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how you'd do it, except you'll want to type the variable holding the return value as `id` or `id<RCParsableObject>`. No need for `performSelector:` or anything like it — that's useful for when the selector is dynamically chosen, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if I understand well the answer, so to create the object I want I do: `id<RCParsableObject> object = [class parseObjectparseObjectFromDictonary:param];` remember than `parseObjectparseObjectFromDictonary:` is a class method. The compiler says me `No known class method for selector 'parseObjectparseObjectFromDictonary:'`

Comment: @Jpellat: Assuming that `'parseObjectparseObjectFromDictonary:'` in your comment was a copy-paste mistake and not actually from your code, that message means the class named by `type` doesn't implement the method. If it wasn't a copy-paste mistake, then you made a typo in your code (writing "parseObjectparseObject" instead of just "parseObject"), which would also explain the problem.

Comment: XD, sorry man, was my mistake. Awesome answer, thanks for your help!